# Can you apply a filter to Google Docs / Drive to reveal all files shared to anybody?

Tags: google-drive

In Google Drive, searching by visibility, my options are:

- Public
- Anyone with a link
- Private
- Not shared

None of these options allow me to search all files shared to specific people only (i.e. shared to other Google users but not public or "with a link").

I've shared files to specific people over the years and would like to clean it up. This filter would make that task magnitudes easier.

Comment: What do you mean by anyone?

Comment: I mean _any_ files that are shared. I'll update the question to be more descriptive.

Comment: This question isn't quite accurate anymore. The new Google Drive search does not provide an option to search by visibility, and doesn't provide options like 'Anyone with a link'.

Answer (score 2):

While in Google Drive. You can type in the search bar:

> to:     Documents shared to someone

```
to:bob@gmail.com
```

This will find all documents shared to an individual. Leaving it blank like this --

> To:

will show all documents shared to anyone.

[Here](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375114) are more details.

Comment: I believe that to: acts as no filter at all.  In my  tests searching on to: finds files that are not shared with anyone.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. I believe it stopped working since a major Google Drive update in 2015.

Comment: This doesn't work. Leaving "to:" empty includes files that are "Restricted" and that are accessible to anyone on the internet. Reading your Google support link, there's no specified way to do this. I don't know how your answer got upvoted. The actual answer is: you have to check the Share settings on each and every file and folder to see which ones are shared to anyone on the internet, or just remember which ones you did.